# Shell script (with top command) not working in cronjob

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

Cron expression:

`# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 * * * * /home/sysadmin/sample.sh`

Shell Script content:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
Vardate=`date`
topresult=`top -n 1| grep Cpu`
# CPUStatus=$Vardate"\t"$topresult
# echo $CPUStatus >> /tmp/data.log
echo $Vardate"   "$topresult >> /tmp/data.log
```

When i exeute the script manually, I get the desired output. Which is:

```
Wed Sep 23 02:42:47 MDT 2015   Cpu(s): 0.3%us, 0.3%sy, 0.0%ni, 99.4%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 0.0%si, 0.0%st
```

But when the cronjob executes it, the output is as follows:

```
Wed Sep 23 02:42:47 MDT 2015
```

What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

Use top's "batch" mode.

replace:

```
topresult=`top -n 1| grep Cpu`
```

with:

```
topresult=`top -b -n 1| grep Cpu`
```

> **-b : Batch mode** operation 
>   Starts top in 'Batch mode', which could be useful for sending output from top to other programs or to a file.
>   In this mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations
>   limit you've set with the '-n' command-line option or until killed.

Source:  http://linux.die.net/man/1/top

Comment: +1 because your solution solves the problem, but it would still be interesting to learn what actually causes the difference between interactive and cron execution. I could reproduce the OP's problem on my box, and apparently it does not matter whether stdin is connected to a tty or not, it does not matter whether the output is piped or redirected, and the executing user does not seem to be the problem either.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but from what I've read, top is written using the curses library which is manipulating the screen using control characters.  Not sure what happens to standard output in this kind of environment. The man pages for ncurses suggests it could possibly be going to stderr:  http://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses  *"If standard output from a ncurses program is re-directed to something which is not a tty, screen updates will be directed to standard error."*  You can also try to get a more normal output by setting TERM=dumb. But the bottom line is that batch mode is what you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

```
export TERM=xterm
FILE_NAME=top-$(date +%Y%m%d).log
top -b -n 1 >> /home/ec2-user/$FILE_NAME
```